# Able to modify the final value in java?

Tags: java

in java i know that **final** variables value cannot be changed. please see the below program and help me how the final value is changed.

```
public class MainClass {

    final static int name=123;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(name+123);
    }
}
```

**Out put is 246****

Thanks!

Comment: Eh? name is not changed at all! Where do you see that it is modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `name` is not changed, there is a temporary value created for the output.
Try

```
name += 123;
```

it will fail to compile.

Answer (score 9):

You are printing `name+123` not `name`  The field `name` hasn't changed.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(name+123);
System.out.println(name); // run it again with this line
```

Answer (score 0):

The final value is not changed. The java just did arithmentic `System.out.println(name+123);` is 246.

Running `System.out.println(name);` after that should be 123

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually modifying the value of `name` when you call `System.out.println(name+123)`.

If you were to print the value of `name` after this, you would see that it is still 123.

```
System.out.println(name);    // prints 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not change the final variable, but print it with the sum of 123. The value of name is 123 and it sum with 123 and then displayed.

Imagine a third variable build runtime, which is said to contain the sum of **name** and **123** and then it is said to print it.

Add one more line below this one:

```
System.out.println(name); // This would print your variable's current value
```